# Adding annotations to Google candlestick chart (Posted solution triggers TypeError)

Tags: javascript, charts, annotations, google-visualization

I am trying to add some annotations to a Google Candlestick chart. I noticed someone had already asked this same question ([Adding annotations to Google Candlestick chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534909/adding-annotations-to-google-candlestick-chart)). The user    [Aperçu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054072/aper%C3%A7u/) replied with a detailed solution to extend the chart and add annotations since the chart doesn't have any such feature built in. However, when I try this solution I get an error "TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[0] is undefined"

Here is my code:

```
        chartPoints = [
            ['Budget', 0, 0, 9999, 9999, 'foo1'],
            ['Sales', 0, 0, 123, 123, 'foo2'],
            ['Backlog', 123, 123, 456, 456, 'foo3'],
            ['Hard Forecast', 456, 456, 789, 789, 'foo4'],
            ['Sales to Budget', 789, 789, 1000, 1000, 'foo5']
        ];
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartPoints, true);
        data.setColumnProperty(5, 'role', 'annotation');
        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            bar: { groupWidth: '40%', width: '100%' },
            candlestick: {
                fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' },
                risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }
            }
        };    

        var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        // attempt to use Aperçu's solution
        const bars = document.querySelectorAll('#chart_div svg > g:nth-child(5) > g')[0].lastChild.children // this triggers a TypeError
        for (var i = 0 ; i < bars.length ; i++) {
          const bar = bars[i]
          const { top, left, width } = bar.getBoundingClientRect()
          const hint = document.createElement('div')
          hint.style.top = top + 'px'
          hint.style.left = left + width + 5 + 'px'
          hint.classList.add('hint')
          hint.innerText = rawData.filter(t => t[1])[i][0]
          document.getElementById('chart_div').append(hint)
        }
```

I want the chart to show the last piece of data next to the bars (i.e. "foo1", "foo2", etc)

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857399/5090771)...

Comment: Hi, that's a really long answer and I'm not really sure what I need to change to make it work with my code. I tried pasting in the bottom part (everything from var waterFallChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({ to the bottom minus the jquery thing at the end) but I get error  ReferenceError: dataChart is not defined. It's just a lot to take in. Can you explain to me how I can refactor this to make it work with my code above?

Comment: I tried changing dataChart to chartPoints but now I'm getting Error: Unknown header type: 0

Comment: Well, just an update, I was able to get some of the bars to display the text in the 5th column next to them by doing #chart_div svg > g:nth-child(3) > g. However the text only appears for the first 3 bars and I get the error TypeError: chartPoints.filter(...)[i] is undefined. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each candle or bar will be represented by a `<rect>` element

we can use the rise and fall colors to separate the bars from other `<rect>` elements in the chart

there will be the same number of bars as rows in the data table

once we find the first bar, we can use `rowIndex` of zero to pull values from the data

we need to find the value of the rise / fall, to know where to place the annotation

then use chart methods to find the location for the annotation

> `getChartLayoutInterface()` - Returns an object containing information about the onscreen placement of the chart and its elements.
>
> `getYLocation(position, optional_axis_index)` - Returns the screen y-coordinate of position relative to the chart's container.

see following working snippet
two annotations are added
one for the difference in rise and fall
and the other for the value in the column with annotation role

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var chartPoints = [
    ['Budget', 0, 0, 9999, 9999, 'foo1'],
    ['Sales', 0, 0, 123, 123, 'foo2'],
    ['Backlog', 123, 123, 456, 456, 'foo3'],
    ['Hard Forecast', 456, 456, 789, 789, 'foo4'],
    ['Sales to Budget', 789, 789, 1000, 1000, 'foo5']
  ];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartPoints, true);
  data.setColumnProperty(5, 'role', 'annotation');
  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    bar: { groupWidth: '40%', width: '100%' },
    candlestick: {
      fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' },
      risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var annotation;
    var bars;
    var chartLayout;
    var formatNumber;
    var positionY;
    var positionX;
    var rowBalance;
    var rowBottom;
    var rowIndex;
    var rowTop;
    var rowValue;
    var rowWidth;

    chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    rowIndex = 0;
    formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '#,##0'
    });

    bars = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
      switch (bars[i].getAttribute('fill')) {
        case '#a52714':
        case '#0f9d58':
          rowWidth = parseFloat(bars[i].getAttribute('width'));
          if (rowWidth > 2) {
            rowBottom = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1);
            rowTop = data.getValue(rowIndex, 3);
            rowValue = rowTop - rowBottom;
            rowBalance = Math.max(rowBottom, rowTop);
            positionY = chartLayout.getYLocation(rowBalance) - 6;
            positionX = parseFloat(bars[i].getAttribute('x'));

            // row value
            annotation = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(container.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].cloneNode(true));
            annotation.textContent = formatNumber.formatValue(rowValue);
            annotation.setAttribute('x', (positionX + (rowWidth / 2)));
            annotation.setAttribute('y', positionY);
            annotation.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');

            // annotation column
            annotation = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(container.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].cloneNode(true));
            annotation.textContent = data.getValue(rowIndex, 5);
            annotation.setAttribute('x', (positionX + (rowWidth / 2)));
            annotation.setAttribute('y', positionY - 18);
            annotation.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');

            rowIndex++;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Whitehat, thank you for the detailed explanation and code example. I am trying to modify this to work without jquery but am having a small problem. I changed the lines starting with "$(annotation)" to a for loop for (var i=0; i < annotation.length; i++) { annotation[i].innerHTML(formatNumber.formatValue(rowValue)); } but for some reason I'm just getting the field label "Budget" instead of the "foo1", "foo2", etc. Is there a way to do this without jquery?

Comment: Ah my mistake, forgot that innerHTML is an attribute not a method! I got it working without jquery and the for loop wasn't necessary either. Just needed to change each instance of $(annotation).text(value); with annotation.innerHTML = value; Thanks for the help WhiteHat!

Comment: add annotation.removeAttribute("transform"); and annotation.setAttribute('text-anchor', "middle"); if your text gets slanted