# Google horizontal bar chart annotations overlapping vAxis

Tags: google-visualization

I have a simple horizontal bar chart with inside annotations. When plotting small values, the annotations overflow to the left and overlap the vAxis labels:

[image]

My preference is for inside annotations if possible, but as a workaround I tried adding `alwaysOutside:true` to the annotation options which created overlapping issues on the right:

[image]

Is there a way to make these annotations dynamic so they display inside when there is enough room and outside when there isn't?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5j0tkx2e/

Comment: I've tried every configuration and version of google charts I could, all with the same results. it may require adding your own annotations, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074199/5090771), though with a different chart type. if you want to take the custom route and get stuck, I can try to help...

Comment: How about setting a vAxis viewWindow.min of 1500.